# How can one visit an isolated island?

Tags: safety, nature-and-wildlife, islands, vacations, atlantic-ocean

If I want to spend a few days on an isolated (but not deserted) island, what are my options?

I know that there are several deserted islands near and around New York, New Jersey and Maryland. I am not talking about them. The ideal one(s) I am looking for would have:

- some basic living necessities (a small house or hut, electricity, running water etc.)
- without wild animals (these [ones](http://www.discoveryuk.com/web/survival-zone/plants-and-Animals/dangerous-animals/), or those which typically make a horror movie plot)
- isolation
- be in touch with the world in case of an emergency
- doesn't require to spend $1000s per day

So the question is: *Can one go to such an island on vacation?*

---

I am preferably looking near the Eastern coastline of USA.

Comment: In the Philippines and Indonesia, this is easily achieved.

Comment: Rent a boat and just tie it to a tree.  It's not unheard of to do something similar in Virginia.  If you need to find a hut or something then there are plenty of those too you could ask to shack up there for a few days.  A few fishing hovels too are relatively deserted.

Comment: You mean, without big or dangerous animals? It's quite impossible to find any place on earth with exception of somewhere middle in Antarctida without animals at all...

Comment: @easymoden00b Where can I find tree in the middle of water? I park my car under a tree to get that kind of isolation. Btw, What is a *fishing hovel*?

Comment: There are PLENTY of trees that are positioned right next to the waters edge. A _hovel_ is a small simple dwelling.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how isolated you are looking for, there are plenty of cottages for rent on islands in Ontario. Here is a [search result for island cottages on one site](http://cottagevacations.com/island-cottages). Costs are from a few hundred per day. Some of these are not very isolated - only a few hundred yards from other cottages across the water, and may have boaters coming close to the island. All of them have the usual amenities.

Here are some [more remote island rentals](http://rent.privateislandsonline.com/areas/ontario), from $500 per night.

I'm sure there are similar cottages for rent in New York.

Answer (score 0):

I warmly recommend a trip to [Channel Islands National Park](http://www.nps.gov/chis/index.htm).  There are taps, pit toilets, a visitor centre, and accommodation for the park rangers.  It's at the "wrong" coast, though.